# ms sql server select time data order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in ms sql server named table1 , if I execute 
select time,data from table 1 it shows

```
 time  |data
-------|------
 08:00 |a
 10:00 |b
 12:00 |c
```

I need to query a while for all times increment by 1 hour, the results must be like below :

```
 time  |data
-------|------
 08:00 | a
 09:00 | empty
 10:00 |b
 11:00 | empty
 12:00 |c
 13:00 | empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
declare @mn time, @mx time
select @mn=MIN([time]), @mx=MAX([time]) from @tbl

;with T as(
    select 
        [time], 
        data
    from tbl 
    where [time]=@mn

    union all
    select DATEADD(hour, 1,T.[time]),
    (select b.data from tbl b where DATEADD(hour, 1,T.[time])=b.[time])
    from T 
    where [time]<=@mx)
select 
    time, 
    ISNULL(data, 'empty') data 
from T
```

Answer (score 0):

I approach these types of problems by first generating the list that you want (of times, in this case) and then using `left outer join` to combine the original data.

The following uses a recursive CTE to generate the list.  It starts by determining the minimum and maximum values of time, and then using recursion to generate the list:

```
with minmax as (
      select min(time) as mintime, max(time) as maxtime
      from table t
     ),
     times(thetime, maxtime) as (
      select mintime as thetime, maxtime
      from minmax
      union all
      select dateadd(hour, 1, thetime), maxtime
      from times
      where thetime < maxtime
     )
select times.thetime, t.data
from times left outer join
     table1 t
     on t.time = times.thetime;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17237) is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating it.

Comment: Thank you for your response , but the first two answers does not work , thank you for your time ,